# Not working a background job with using Resque on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, redis, resque, resque-scheduler

I have my rails application that has a job (using `Active Job`). I use `resque` and `resque-scheduler` gems for queuing backend.

I want to connect my rails application to a redis-to-go server with Resque on Heroku but I get many error messages on my logs, like this:

```
2019-12-01T12:04:00.942767+00:00 app[worker.1]: resque-scheduler: [INFO] 2019-12-01T12:04:00+00:00: Error connecting to Redis on localhost:6379 (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)
2019-12-01T12:04:01.945657+00:00 app[worker.1]: resque-scheduler: [INFO] 2019-12-01T12:04:01+00:00: Error connecting to Redis on localhost:6379 (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)
2019-12-01T12:04:02.990485+00:00 app[worker.1]: resque-scheduler: [INFO] 2019-12-01T12:04:02+00:00: Error connecting to Redis on localhost:6379 (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)
2019-12-01T12:04:04.004590+00:00 app[worker.1]: resque-scheduler: [INFO] 2019-12-01T12:04:04+00:00: Error connecting to Redis on localhost:6379 (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)
2019-12-01T12:04:05.012344+00:00 app[worker.1]: resque-scheduler: [INFO] 2019-12-01T12:04:05+00:00: Error connecting to Redis on localhost:6379 (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)
```

Everything works on development and production environments, but doesn't work on Heroku. I found many questions with a similar problem, but their solutions didn't help me.

I get an error message `Error connecting to Redis on localhost:6379 (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)` from `redis` [gem](https://github.com/redis/redis-rb/blob/master/lib/redis/client.rb#L343) in the `establish_connection` method. But when I figure out the necessary values from rails console, I understand there is OK.

```
$ heroku run rails console

Loading production environment (Rails 5.2.3)
irb(main):001:0> Resque.redis
=> #<Resque::DataStore:0x00005643758bd968 @redis=<Redis::Namespace v1.6.0 with client v4.1.2 for redis://spinyfin.redistogo.com:11302/0/resque>, @queue_access=#<Resque::DataStore::QueueAccess:0x00005643758bd8f0 @redis=<Redis::Namespace v1.6.0 with client v4.1.2 for redis://spinyfin.redistogo.com:11302/0/resque>>, @failed_queue_access=#<Resque::DataStore::FailedQueueAccess:0x00005643758bd8c8 @redis=<Redis::Namespace v1.6.0 with client v4.1.2 for redis://spinyfin.redistogo.com:11302/0/resque>>, @workers=#<Resque::DataStore::Workers:0x00005643758bd8a0 @redis=<Redis::Namespace v1.6.0 with client v4.1.2 for redis://spinyfin.redistogo.com:11302/0/resque>>, @stats_access=#<Resque::DataStore::StatsAccess:0x00005643758bd878 @redis=<Redis::Namespace v1.6.0 with client v4.1.2 for redis://spinyfin.redistogo.com:11302/0/resque>>>

irb(main):002:0> REDIS._client
=> #<Redis::Client:0x00005643758be9f8 @options={:url=>"redis://redistogo:4822b22abf6b11bd0830af5f5797c0fb@spinyfin.redistogo.com:11302/", :scheme=>"redis", :host=>"spinyfin.redistogo.com", :port=>11302, :path=>nil, :timeout=>5.0, :password=>"4822b22abf6b11bd0830af5f5797c0fb", :db=>0, :driver=>Redis::Connection::Ruby, :id=>nil, :tcp_keepalive=>0, :reconnect_attempts=>1, :reconnect_delay=>0.0, :reconnect_delay_max=>0.5, :inherit_socket=>false, :role=>:master, :connect_timeout=>5.0, :read_timeout=>5.0, :write_timeout=>5.0, :_parsed=>true}, @reconnect=true, @logger=nil, @connection=nil, @command_map={}, @pending_reads=0, @connector=#<Redis::Client::Connector:0x00005643758bdc60 @options={:url=>"redis://redistogo:4822b22abf6b11bd0830af5f5797c0fb@spinyfin.redistogo.com:11302/", :scheme=>"redis", :host=>"spinyfin.redistogo.com", :port=>11302, :path=>nil, :timeout=>5.0, :password=>"4822b22abf6b11bd0830af5f5797c0fb", :db=>0, :driver=>Redis::Connection::Ruby, :id=>nil, :tcp_keepalive=>0, :reconnect_attempts=>1, :reconnect_delay=>0.0, :reconnect_delay_max=>0.5, :inherit_socket=>false, :role=>:master, :connect_timeout=>5.0, :read_timeout=>5.0, :write_timeout=>5.0, :_parsed=>true}>>
```

Moreover, I understand that the settings for `resque` and `resque-scheduler` gems work correct after restart my application on Heroku, but for some reason Resque connects to `localhost:6379` instead of a redis-to-go server. Have you any ideas, why this happens? And how I can solve this problem?

I have provided the necessary information about my settings, using gems, etc below.

=========================================================================

**Console logs after `heroku restart`**

https://pastebin.com/E9YkxeEP (Body is limited to 30000 characters, sorry)

**Gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.1.0', require: false
gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.3.1'
gem 'faker'
gem 'foreman'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'local_time'
gem 'pg', '>= 0.18', '< 2.0'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.3'
gem 'redis'
gem 'resque'
gem 'resque-scheduler'
gem 'resque-scheduler-web'
gem 'resque-web', require: 'resque_web'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'action-cable-testing'
  gem 'byebug', platforms: %i[mri mingw x64_mingw]
  gem 'factory_bot_rails'
  gem 'pry-rails'
  gem 'rails-controller-testing'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.8'
  gem 'rubocop'
  gem 'timecop'
end

group :development do
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
end

gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: %i[mingw mswin x64_mingw jruby]
```

**Gemfile.lock**

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    action-cable-testing (0.6.0)
      actioncable (>= 5.0)
    actioncable (5.2.3)
      actionpack (= 5.2.3)
      nio4r (~> 2.0)
      websocket-driver (>= 0.6.1)
    actionmailer (5.2.3)
      actionpack (= 5.2.3)
      actionview (= 5.2.3)
      activejob (= 5.2.3)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
    actionpack (5.2.3)
      actionview (= 5.2.3)
      activesupport (= 5.2.3)
      rack (~> 2.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.6.3)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    actionview (5.2.3)
      activesupport (= 5.2.3)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubi (~> 1.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.3)
    activejob (5.2.3)
      activesupport (= 5.2.3)
      globalid (>= 0.3.6)
    activemodel (5.2.3)
      activesupport (= 5.2.3)
    activerecord (5.2.3)
      activemodel (= 5.2.3)
      activesupport (= 5.2.3)
      arel (>= 9.0)
    activestorage (5.2.3)
      actionpack (= 5.2.3)
      activerecord (= 5.2.3)
      marcel (~> 0.3.1)
    activesupport (5.2.3)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
      i18n (>= 0.7, < 2)
      minitest (~> 5.1)
      tzinfo (~> 1.1)
    arel (9.0.0)
    ast (2.4.0)
    autoprefixer-rails (9.6.1.1)
      execjs
    bindex (0.8.1)
    bootsnap (1.4.5)
      msgpack (~> 1.0)
    bootstrap (4.3.1)
      autoprefixer-rails (>= 9.1.0)
      popper_js (>= 1.14.3, < 2)
      sassc-rails (>= 2.0.0)
    builder (3.2.3)
    byebug (11.0.1)
    coderay (1.1.2)
    coffee-rails (5.0.0)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (>= 5.2.0)
    coffee-script (2.4.1)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.12.2)
    commonjs (0.2.7)
    concurrent-ruby (1.1.5)
    crass (1.0.4)
    diff-lcs (1.3)
    erubi (1.8.0)
    et-orbi (1.2.2)
      tzinfo
    execjs (2.7.0)
    factory_bot (5.1.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
    factory_bot_rails (5.1.0)
      factory_bot (~> 5.1.0)
      railties (>= 4.2.0)
    faker (1.9.3)
      i18n (>= 0.7)
    ffi (1.11.1)
    font-awesome-sass (5.11.2)
      sassc (>= 1.11)
    foreman (0.86.0)
    fugit (1.3.3)
      et-orbi (~> 1.1, >= 1.1.8)
      raabro (~> 1.1)
    globalid (0.4.2)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
    i18n (1.6.0)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
    jaro_winkler (1.5.3)
    jquery-rails (4.3.5)
      rails-dom-testing (>= 1, < 3)
      railties (>= 4.2.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    less (2.6.0)
      commonjs (~> 0.2.7)
    less-rails (2.8.0)
      actionpack (>= 4.0)
      less (~> 2.6.0)
      sprockets (> 2, < 4)
      tilt
    listen (3.1.5)
      rb-fsevent (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.4)
      rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.7)
      ruby_dep (~> 1.2)
    local_time (2.1.0)
    loofah (2.2.3)
      crass (~> 1.0.2)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.9)
    mail (2.7.1)
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.1)
    marcel (0.3.3)
      mimemagic (~> 0.3.2)
    method_source (0.9.2)
    mimemagic (0.3.3)
    mini_mime (1.0.2)
    mini_portile2 (2.4.0)
    minitest (5.11.3)
    mono_logger (1.1.0)
    msgpack (1.3.1)
    multi_json (1.14.1)
    mustermann (1.0.3)
    nio4r (2.5.1)
    nokogiri (1.10.4)
      mini_portile2 (~> 2.4.0)
    parallel (1.17.0)
    parser (2.6.3.0)
      ast (~> 2.4.0)
    pg (1.1.4)
    popper_js (1.14.5)
    pry (0.12.2)
      coderay (~> 1.1.0)
      method_source (~> 0.9.0)
    pry-rails (0.3.9)
      pry (>= 0.10.4)
    puma (3.12.1)
    raabro (1.1.6)
    rack (2.0.7)
    rack-protection (2.0.7)
      rack
    rack-test (1.1.0)
      rack (>= 1.0, < 3)
    rails (5.2.3)
      actioncable (= 5.2.3)
      actionmailer (= 5.2.3)
      actionpack (= 5.2.3)
      actionview (= 5.2.3)
      activejob (= 5.2.3)
      activemodel (= 5.2.3)
      activerecord (= 5.2.3)
      activestorage (= 5.2.3)
      activesupport (= 5.2.3)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0)
      railties (= 5.2.3)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0.0)
    rails-controller-testing (1.0.4)
      actionpack (>= 5.0.1.x)
      actionview (>= 5.0.1.x)
      activesupport (>= 5.0.1.x)
    rails-dom-testing (2.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
      nokogiri (>= 1.6)
    rails-html-sanitizer (1.2.0)
      loofah (~> 2.2, >= 2.2.2)
    railties (5.2.3)
      actionpack (= 5.2.3)
      activesupport (= 5.2.3)
      method_source
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.19.0, < 2.0)
    rainbow (3.0.0)
    rake (12.3.3)
    rb-fsevent (0.10.3)
    rb-inotify (0.10.0)
      ffi (~> 1.0)
    redis (4.1.2)
    redis-namespace (1.6.0)
      redis (>= 3.0.4)
    resque (2.0.0)
      mono_logger (~> 1.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      redis-namespace (~> 1.6)
      sinatra (>= 0.9.2)
      vegas (~> 0.1.2)
    resque-scheduler (4.4.0)
      mono_logger (~> 1.0)
      redis (>= 3.3)
      resque (>= 1.26)
      rufus-scheduler (~> 3.2)
    resque-scheduler-web (1.1.0)
      resque-scheduler (~> 4.0)
      resque-web (~> 0.0.8)
    resque-web (0.0.12)
      coffee-rails
      font-awesome-sass
      jquery-rails
      resque
      sass-rails
      twitter-bootstrap-rails
    rspec-core (3.8.2)
      rspec-support (~> 3.8.0)
    rspec-expectations (3.8.4)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.2.0, < 2.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.8.0)
    rspec-mocks (3.8.1)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.2.0, < 2.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.8.0)
    rspec-rails (3.8.2)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      railties (>= 3.0)
      rspec-core (~> 3.8.0)
      rspec-expectations (~> 3.8.0)
      rspec-mocks (~> 3.8.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.8.0)
    rspec-support (3.8.2)
    rubocop (0.72.0)
      jaro_winkler (~> 1.5.1)
      parallel (~> 1.10)
      parser (>= 2.6)
      rainbow (>= 2.2.2, < 4.0)
      ruby-progressbar (~> 1.7)
      unicode-display_width (>= 1.4.0, < 1.7)
    ruby-progressbar (1.10.1)
    ruby_dep (1.5.0)
    rufus-scheduler (3.6.0)
      fugit (~> 1.1, >= 1.1.6)
    sass (3.7.4)
      sass-listen (~> 4.0.0)
    sass-listen (4.0.0)
      rb-fsevent (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.4)
      rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.7)
    sass-rails (5.1.0)
      railties (>= 5.2.0)
      sass (~> 3.1)
      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)
      tilt (>= 1.1, < 3)
    sassc (2.2.0)
      ffi (~> 1.9)
    sassc-rails (2.1.2)
      railties (>= 4.0.0)
      sassc (>= 2.0)
      sprockets (> 3.0)
      sprockets-rails
      tilt
    sinatra (2.0.7)
      mustermann (~> 1.0)
      rack (~> 2.0)
      rack-protection (= 2.0.7)
      tilt (~> 2.0)
    spring (2.1.0)
    spring-watcher-listen (2.0.1)
      listen (>= 2.7, < 4.0)
      spring (>= 1.2, < 3.0)
    sprockets (3.7.2)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
      rack (> 1, < 3)
    sprockets-rails (3.2.1)
      actionpack (>= 4.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.0)
      sprockets (>= 3.0.0)
    thor (0.20.3)
    thread_safe (0.3.6)
    tilt (2.0.9)
    timecop (0.9.1)
    turbolinks (5.2.1)
      turbolinks-source (~> 5.2)
    turbolinks-source (5.2.0)
    twitter-bootstrap-rails (4.0.0)
      actionpack (~> 5.0, >= 5.0.1)
      execjs (~> 2.7)
      less-rails (~> 2.8, >= 2.8.0)
      railties (~> 5.0, >= 5.0.1)
    tzinfo (1.2.5)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
    uglifier (4.1.20)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0, < 3)
    unicode-display_width (1.6.0)
    vegas (0.1.11)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
    web-console (3.7.0)
      actionview (>= 5.0)
      activemodel (>= 5.0)
      bindex (>= 0.4.0)
      railties (>= 5.0)
    websocket-driver (0.7.1)
      websocket-extensions (>= 0.1.0)
    websocket-extensions (0.1.4)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  action-cable-testing
  bootsnap (>= 1.1.0)
  bootstrap (~> 4.3.1)
  byebug
  factory_bot_rails
  faker
  foreman
  jquery-rails
  listen (>= 3.0.5, < 3.2)
  local_time
  pg (>= 0.18, < 2.0)
  pry-rails
  puma (~> 3.11)
  rails (~> 5.2.3)
  rails-controller-testing
  redis
  resque
  resque-scheduler
  resque-scheduler-web
  resque-web
  rspec-rails (~> 3.8)
  rubocop
  sass-rails (~> 5.0)
  spring
  spring-watcher-listen (~> 2.0.0)
  timecop
  turbolinks (~> 5)
  tzinfo-data
  uglifier (>= 1.3.0)
  web-console (>= 3.3.0)

BUNDLED WITH
   1.17.2
```

**Procfile**

```
worker: RESQUE_SCHEDULER_INTERVAL=1 INTERVAL=1 QUEUE=leramiz* COUNT=1 TERM_CHILD=1 RESQUE_TERM_TIMEOUT=10 bundle exec rake resque:schedule_and_work
```

**lib/tasks/resque.rake**

```
require 'resque/tasks'
require 'resque/scheduler/tasks'

task 'resque:preload' => :environment

namespace :resque do
  # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51757169/how-do-you-schedule-resque-jobs-on-heroku
  # https://grosser.it/2012/04/14/resque-scheduler-on-heroku-without-extra-workers/
  desc 'schedule and work, so we only need 1 dyno'
  task :schedule_and_work do
    if Process.respond_to?(:fork)
      if Process.fork
        sh('rake environment resque:work')
      else
        sh('rake resque:scheduler')
        Process.wait
      end
    else # windows
      pid = Process.spawn 'rake environment resque:work'
      Rake::Task['resque:scheduler'].invoke
      Process.wait(pid)
    end
  end

  task :setup do
    require 'resque'
  end

  task setup_schedule: :setup do
    require 'resque-scheduler'
  end

  task scheduler: :setup_schedule
end
```

**config/initializers/resque.rb**

```
require 'resque/server'

if Rails.env.development?
  Resque.redis = Redis.new(host: 'localhost', port: '6379')
else
  REDIS = Redis.new(url: ENV['REDISTOGO_URL'])
  Resque.redis = REDIS
end

Resque.logger = Logger.new(Rails.root.join('log', "#{Rails.env}_resque.log"))
Resque.logger.level = Logger::DEBUG
```

**config/environments/production.rb**

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # Code is not reloaded between requests.
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
  # your application in memory, allowing both threaded web servers
  # and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
  # Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
  config.eager_load = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Ensures that a master key has been made available in either ENV["RAILS_MASTER_KEY"]
  # or in config/master.key. This key is used to decrypt credentials (and other encrypted files).
  # config.require_master_key = true

  # Disable serving static files from the `/public` folder by default since
  # Apache or NGINX already handles this.
  config.public_file_server.enabled = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
  config.assets.js_compressor = config.assets.js_compressor = Uglifier.new(harmony: true)
  # config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

  # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  config.assets.compile = false

  # `config.assets.precompile` and `config.assets.version` have moved to config/initializers/assets.rb

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = 'http://assets.example.com'

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files.
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Sendfile' # for Apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for NGINX

  # Mount Action Cable outside main process or domain
  # config.action_cable.mount_path = nil
  config.action_cable.url = 'wss://cuurjol-leramiz.herokuapp.com/cable'
  config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = %w[http://cuurjol-leramiz.herokuapp.com/cable https://cuurjol-leramiz.herokuapp.com/cable]

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  # config.force_ssl = true

  # Use the lowest log level to ensure availability of diagnostic information
  # when problems arise.
  config.log_level = :debug

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
  config.log_tags = [:request_id]

  # Use a different cache store in production.
  config.cache_store = :redis_cache_store, { url: ENV['REDISTOGO_URL'] }

  # Use a real queuing backend for Active Job (and separate queues per environment)
  config.active_job.queue_adapter     = :resque
  config.active_job.queue_name_prefix = "leramiz_#{Rails.env}"

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation cannot be found).
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups.
  # require 'syslog/logger'
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(Syslog::Logger.new 'app-name')

  if ENV['RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT'].present?
    logger           = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDOUT)
    logger.formatter = config.log_formatter
    config.logger    = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(logger)
  end

  # Do not dump schema after migrations.
  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
end
```

**app/jobs/destroy_private_job.rb**

```
class DestroyPrivateRoomJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  def perform(room)
    users = room.users.to_a
    room.destroy
    ActionCable.server.broadcast('room_management_channel', room: room.as_json(only: %i[id is_private token]),
                                                            status: 'destroyed')

    room_users_list = { room_id: room.id, users: room.users.uniq.as_json(only: :nickname) }
    ActionCable.server.broadcast('room_users_list_channel', room_users_list: room_users_list)

    users.each do |user|
      Rails.cache.write("message_for_user:#{user.id}", "Expiration time for Room ##{room.id} is over")
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: You just gave everyone your redis username and password above

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Your redis client example shows the redis connection URL: `redistogo:4822b22abf6b11bd0830af5f5797c0fb@spinyfin` which has the username and password for your instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a snippet of code in the **lib/tasks/resque.rake** file:

```
  task :schedule_and_work do
    if Process.respond_to?(:fork)
      if Process.fork
        sh('rake environment resque:work')
      else
        sh('rake resque:scheduler')
        Process.wait
      end
    else # windows
      pid = Process.spawn 'rake environment resque:work'
      Rake::Task['resque:scheduler'].invoke
      Process.wait(pid)
    end
  end
```

Replace this on the following:

```
  task :schedule_and_work do
    if Process.respond_to?(:fork)
      if Process.fork
        sh('rake environment resque:work')
      else
        sh('rake environment resque:scheduler')
        Process.wait
      end
    else # windows
      pid = Process.spawn 'rake environment resque:work'
      Rake::Task['environment resque:scheduler'].invoke
      Process.wait(pid)
    end
  end
```

The difference between them is that I added a word `environment` for `resque:scheduler` rake task. I don't know why it is so important, but it works. After that I get correct messages instead of error messages:

```
2019-12-03T20:24:48.131365+00:00 app[worker.1]: rake environment resque:work
2019-12-03T20:24:48.131606+00:00 app[worker.1]: rake environment resque:scheduler
2019-12-03T20:24:50.913986+00:00 app[worker.1]: resque-scheduler: [INFO] 2019-12-03T20:24:50+00:00: Starting
2019-12-03T20:24:50.914027+00:00 app[worker.1]: resque-scheduler: [INFO] 2019-12-03T20:24:50+00:00: Master scheduler
2019-12-03T20:24:50.914137+00:00 app[worker.1]: resque-scheduler: [INFO] 2019-12-03T20:24:50+00:00: Reloading Schedule
2019-12-03T20:24:50.918571+00:00 app[worker.1]: resque-scheduler: [INFO] 2019-12-03T20:24:50+00:00: Loading Schedule
2019-12-03T20:24:50.919477+00:00 app[worker.1]: resque-scheduler: [INFO] 2019-12-03T20:24:50+00:00: Schedule empty! Set Resque.schedule
2019-12-03T20:24:50.919543+00:00 app[worker.1]: resque-scheduler: [INFO] 2019-12-03T20:24:50+00:00: Schedules Loaded
2019-12-03T20:24:50.920549+00:00 app[worker.1]: resque-scheduler: [INFO] 2019-12-03T20:24:50+00:00: Processing Delayed Items
```

Answer (score 0):

Their docs make it look like you only need to set the URL for redis and not an instance of redis https://github.com/resque/resque/blob/master/README.markdown#configuration

Comment: There is no difference between my way of setting URL for redis in **config/initializers/resque.rb** file and their documentation. I tried both variations and they does't work for me.